# Batch script or CMD for daily task on directory content by date

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I admit I am a noob when it comes to CMD and bat scripting hence maybe my question has already been answered but I couldn't find it because I am unfamiliar with the terminology.

Basically I am currently running CMD to create a txt file for a directory content, that works fine but I would like to improve this process and started to look into a batch file to run this for multiple directories and by date but only get confused with the commands.

I would really appreciated if you maybe show me the right direction to look up the possible commands. Here is was I am basically trying to achieve:

- Scan Directory 1, create log file with all content (filename) with modification of date DDMMYYYY and save under Directory 1 (existing on Desktop)
- Repeat above for Directory 2, 3, 4 etc.

Now I am not sure how to approach this and where to start. It looks so simply yet I am have not managed to get to work.

Comment: Are you restricted to CMD? It would be a lot easier to do this in PowerShell (or even VBScript).

Comment: HI, not restricted to CMD. Could use as well PowerShell or VBSscript. I am just afraid that I don't have the needed knowhow for this (yet).

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are on Vista or better and your date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`:

```
for /d %%a in ("%userprofile%\Desktop\Directory*") do (
    for %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do (
        set "fname=%%~fb"
        for /f %%c in ("%%~tb") do set "fdate=%%c"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo !fname! !fdate:/=! >> "%%~fa\LOGFILE.TXT"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your batch script to parse current date-time will be locale specific. As long as you do not plan to use it on non-US Windows it will be fine. My solution was to use simple VBS script to generate current timestamps

So code of my batch file looks like

```
@echo off
call GetToday.bat
call %TEMP%\SetToday.bat
SET LOGFILE=Log.%TODAY%.log
echo %LOGFILE%
Use your log here
```

GetToday.bat:

```
@echo off
set TOOLS_HOME=%~dp0
cscript /NoLogo %TOOLS_HOME%\Today.vbs >%TEMP%\SetToday.bat
call %TEMP%\SetToday.bat
```

Today.vbs:

```
Dim d
d = Now
WScript.Echo "SET TODAY=" & Get2Digit(Year(d)) & Get2Digit(Month(d)) & Get2Digit(Day(d))

Function Get2Digit(value)
    if 10 > value Then
        Get2Digit = "0" & value
    Else
        Get2Digit = Right(value, 2)
    End If
End Function
```

However given Today.vbs generates today date in form YYMMDD. From my experience such suffixes are much more useful, you could just sort you files by name to find specific date

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell something like this should work:

```
$folders = 'C:\path\to\Directory1', 'C:\path\to\Directory2', ...
$refDate = (Get-Date '2013-05-27').Date
$recurse = $false

foreach ($d in $folders) {
  $output = Join-Path $d 'filelist.txt'
  Get-ChildItem $d -Recurse:$recurse | ? {
    -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $refDate
  } | % { $_.Name } | Out-File $output
}
```

If you want to recurse into the subfolders of the scanned folders you need to change `$recurse` to `$true` and perhaps change `$_.Name` to `$_.FullName`, so you get the filename with the full path instead of just the filename.